# Competitive Programming : How to check if a the value of a variable is present in python list?

Tags: python, list, conditional-statements

This following question was asked in one of my aptitude tests .I tried solving using python.The question is as follows :

```
   COVID19 Patients are with identity numbers from 1 to 10. 
But few patients are escaped from quarantine. 
Find out those patients and write their names and details.
 Below are details of patients.

 1 Raju 
2 Ravi 
3 Lakshmi 
4 Yash 
5 Renu 
6 Tanvi 
7 Usha 
8 Vicky 
9 Rocky

10 Manu
```

The format of output and input is as follows:

```
Input Format

Line 1: String
Line 2: String 
Line 3: String 
Line 4: String 
Line 5: String 
Line 6: String 
Line 7: String 
Line 8: String
Line 9: String


Constraints

None

Output Format

Line 1: String
```

The sample input and output is given as :

```
Sample Input 0

Raju
Ravi 
Lakshmi
Yash
Tanvi
Usha
Vicky
Rocky 
Manu

Sample Output 0

Renu
```

So I have given the svaed all the names to an array called Patient[].My program for the question is as follows :

```
patient=[
"Raju",
"Ravi",
"Lakshmi",
"Yash",
"Renu",
"Tanvi",
"Usha",
"Vicky",
"Rocky",
"Manu"
]

for i in range(0,):
item=input()
if item not in patient:
    print(item)
```

Comment: Why would you ever iterate over `range(0,)`? That's an empty range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not iterate over a `range(0,)` as there is no end point defined, it must be `range(0,len(patient))`

then this is how your loop looks:

```
for i in range(0,len(patient)):
    item=input()
    if item not in patient:
        print(item)
```